# "PrintTicket provider failed to convert DEVMODE to PrintTicket"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012, printing

few years ago I wrote a WPF (Visual Basic 2012 based) app which included "printing" some report using standard WPF printdialogs/paginators/features....
everyting worked fine since then (2011/2015), and I did not change a line of that working code...
Now I had to change something (not printing related) to that project and of course I checked the printing features as well...
now the "printing" code fails when using it... actually is not the "paginator" code, but accessing the PrintTicket/Que objects fails reporting
"PrintTicket provider failed to convert PrintTicket to DEVMODE. Win32 error: The parameter is incorrect.  "

but it's weird as it does not always fail, and it fails differently with different printers...
using for instance "PDF Creator" virtual printer, it fails writing/settings some properties of my Que object and not others, while using a different printer fails on others...
for instance, PDF Creator virtual printer:

1) myQue.DefaultPrintTicket = myTicket = OK
2) myQue.CurrentJobSettings.Description = "some title" = OK with some printer, FAILS with a different printer

but 2) only fails the very first time it is set, and I can "resolve" "looping" a few times with a minor time sleep.... again, the second or third time it succeded... 
so I wrote an ugly code like

Dim dlg As New PrintDialog
.....

myTicket = dlg.PrintTicket
myQue = dlg.PrintQueue

'-----

' to check in a loop if the interesting

' properties has been set

Dim ticketIsSet(1) As Boolean

For iLoop As Integer = 1 To 5

```
'it can fail with DEVMODE = NULL
Try
    If Not ticketIsSet(0) Then
        myQue.DefaultPrintTicket = myTicket
        ticketIsSet(0) = True
    End If

    If Not ticketIsSet(1) Then
        myQue.CurrentJobSettings.Description = Me.Title
        ticketIsSet(1) = True
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Errors.Add(ex.Message)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1000)
End Try
If ticketIsSet(0) AndAlso ticketIsSet(1) Then Exit For
```

Next

If Errors.Count Then

```
' it's still ok if title can't be set... :( 
If ticketIsSet(0) Then Errors.Clear()
```

End If

so far, "so good" as I get the job done... but only partially... as my Paginator is used to (succesfully) populate a System.Windows.Controls.DocumentViewer... this alternate documentviewer window can later actually print if requested...
and again, with different printers it succed or fail with "PrintTicket provider failed to convert PrintTicket to DEVMODE. Win32 error: The parameter is incorrect.  " exception...

with PDF Creator virtual printer it succed, with a different physical printer it fails...

I tried the very same looping trick as above, like

Dim Errors As New Specialized.StringCollection

Dim bDone As Boolean = False

For iLoop As Integer = 1 To 5

```
Try

    Dim writer As System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter = System.Printing.PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(m_printQueue)
    writer.Write(Me.docViewer.Document.DocumentPaginator, Me.m_printTicket)
    writer = Nothing
    bDone = True

Catch ex As Exception
    Errors.Add(ex.Message)
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.Sleep(1000)
End Try

If bDone Then Exit For
```

Next
If bDone Then Errors.Clear()

If Errors.Count <> 0 Then BasShowErrors(Errors, Me, False)

and here it fails (again, on some printers) on 
writer.Write(Me.docViewer.Document.DocumentPaginator, Me.m_printTicket)
with "PrintTicket provider failed to convert PrintTicket to DEVMODE. Win32 error: The parameter is incorrect.  " exception...

obviously that printer is ok as regards other programs like World, Excel and the like, and it's ok as well with all other (NOT WPF based) projects... and again this only occur "NOW", as it worked like a charme at the time of the initial development...

my current settings are:

Win7 Ultimate sp 1

SQL 2014 Dev Edition (not relevant)

Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate Version 11.0.61219.00 Update 5

Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.6.01055

I even tried "repairing" the NET Framework with NetFramwork Repair Tool (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135) with no success...

any hint is very appreciated :)

### TIA

asql

Comment: I've come accross this a few times recently but have been unable to identify a specifc cause. In some cases unistalling a windows update helps, in others checking MSXML is installed does it, and in others updating the driver.

Comment: hi, and thank you for your input...I've been prompted by MS Community Support to UPDATE my printers's failing drivers... After doing that now it all works fine... but, to me, this is a WPF bug (ok, they say it's a feature) ... Again, I think the WPF implementation should have addressed the problem other ways... And again, other app using the good old WinForm framework work like a charm... WPF IS guilty! :)  thank you